# Featured image doesn't appear in Blog index

Tags: post-thumbnails, blog

I am using a static page for my frontpage, and another page for my blog index.

However, I've noticed that if I use the same code from my page.php file for displaying the featured image (which works fine), it will not show the featured image for the page designed as my blog index page. Why is this?

This is the snippet of code from page.php, from the top of the file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo 'Featured image here';
} ?>
```

But this code will not produce the echoed result when placed in index.php

Comment: Blog index is a page of blog posts, right? How are you setting featured image? What is the filename of the blog index? Are you using page template?

Comment: Correct, I have a page that is set to be the blog index (in Settings > Reading). The filename of the blog index is index.php

Comment: Since it's index.php it does not work, has _post_thumbnail is to be used in the loop.

Comment: wp_get_attachement functions for your purpose.

Comment: Please expand on that, because that's not a valid function. Do you mean `wp_get_attachment_url`? As this returns false too.

Comment: Yes that's not valid function there are set of functions for getting attachment and their attributes.

Comment: OKay, well thanks for your input, but your information was false, as this returns as false when using those set of functions in index.php. I have set the correct answer as below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find an alternative function that correctly calls the featured image set for the Blog index page by using this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( is_home() && get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_option('page_for_posts') );
} ?>
```

Thanks to those for your help

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer, please don't forget to accept this as an answer after two days.

Comment: Hi! You can accept this as the answer so that it won't come up in unanswered questions list.